# How to make file for clear printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

We have a new printer with ability to print clear, gold and silver. I need to know how to setup the file for clear or gold print. If anyone can help :) Thank you.

Comment: You mean a professional printing company or a print machine that prints silver and gold? If it's the first one, you should ask them how they want to receive the file.

Comment: "Clear" here probably means a transparent media or varnish.

Answer (score 2):

- Use a **Spot Color** to fill or stroke the clear, gold or silver objects. I guess those special inks must have a particular name to be recognized by the printer or maybe they have to be a special metallic Pantone, check the printer manual. What is sure is that it has to be a **spot color**
- Go to menu **Window** > **Separations Preview** to see the spot colors used in the document and check the *special color areas* if necessary hiding the C, M, Y and K inks.
- If it's a clear transparent color superimposed, put it in another layer.

[image]

Comment: You should ask the printer since it differs. Oftentimes, with spot clear or spot UV,  black mask files may come into play and the printer can figure out the rest. You can do a separate 100% black mask file for the spot clear/gloss/uv being applied that you can supply separately from the normal CMYK file.